# How to create a condition in excel based in a value of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have this sheet:

```
Father  Barcode
Jon          500
Peter        600
Leon         700
Charlie      800
```

but with much more information, and I would like to create a condition when I input the barcode in another sheet, if the barcode exist the name of father is printed too, like this:

```
Barcode Father
600     Peter
700     Leon
900     No registry
```

I tried this code `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A3,sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,0)), sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,"No registry")`
But didn't work.

Comment: You'll want to use VLOOKUP, or INDEX with MATCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use IFERROR(INDEX(,MATCH())):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(A3,sheet1!$B:$B,0)),"No registry")
```